# Google Glass App Authentication in php

Tags: authentication, google-glass, google-mirror-api

we have google glass app. that need some glass app authentication.
please tell my the step to create glass app authentication with my website.

the scenario is .

when user signup to the my website,user can insert login token to google glass correspondent to their email id , used at the time of signup by using google glass mirror api.

now we will have login token correspondent to email id in the google glass.
then if user wants to connect to my website by google glass, he or she can directly logged in to my website with login token that he/she has submitted at the time of signup.

so please help me to solve this scenario . with the step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Its a pretty long process, and also depends on the functionalities you do want to provide in your authentication flow on Google Glass.

1. Creating Google API Service Account.
2. Providing Metadata about your Glassware.
3. Implementing authentication flow.
   This step is the crux of the authentication flow, It is further divided as follows: (a) User turns Glassware On and is redirected to your sign-in page (b) Service validates user and makes a call to mirror.accounts.insert (c) Mirror API sends the account to the user's Glass device (d) Account information is available with AccountManager.

For more details about the implementation please follow the [official Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication).